# Embeddings of $K \subset K[\alpha] \subset K[\alpha][\beta]$

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I made a conjecture while doing a different problem.

> Let  $K \subset K[\alpha] \subset K[\alpha][\beta]$ be field extensions of degree $n$ and $m$ where $K$ is a perfect field. We know that the $K$ embeddings of $K[\alpha]$ into some larger algebraically closed field (let's say $\mathbb{C}$ for simplicity) are given by $\alpha \rightarrow \text{some conjugate of } \alpha$. Is it true however that the $K$-embeddings of $K[\alpha][\beta]$ are given by the pair $(\alpha, \beta) \rightarrow (\alpha_i, \beta_j)$ where $\alpha_i, \beta_j$ are conjugates of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ respectively.

I feel like intuitively this should be true. But although conjugates are algebraically indistinguishable, $\alpha^i \beta^j$ might not satisfy the properties of our embedding. I am a little lost on how to prove that something is an embedding.